# Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (740, 19, 163, 279)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a 3D CNN on images ( in the form of NumPy arrays ) of dimension (19,163,279). My X_train has a shape of (740,19,163,279) and y_train has a shape of (185,19,163,279).

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    INPUT_SHAPE = (1, 19, 163, 279)
else:
    INPUT_SHAPE = (19, 163, 279, 1)
```

And this is my model

```
def get_model(width=163, height=279, depth=19):
    """Build a 3D convolutional neural network model."""

    inputs = keras.Input(INPUT_SHAPE)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu",padding='same')(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu",padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

    outputs = layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    # Define the model.
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="3dcnn")
    return model


# Build model.
model = get_model(width=163, height=279, depth=19)
model.summary()
```

However, while training using the following code,

```
# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch
epochs = 100
model.fit(
    X_train,
    validation_data=y_test,
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (740, 19, 163, 279)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: according to your data, your INPUT_SHAPE must be (19, 163, 279)... no need to add another dimensionality. also, I don't know why you are fitting without labels (y=None) and using y_test only as validation_data

Comment: Labels are there. I just did not include that part of the code in the question. And I changed INPUT_SHAPE to (19,163,279) from (1,19,163,279) and (19,163,279,1). But now I am getting a new error, "Input 0 of layer conv3d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 19, 163, 279]
"

Comment: for your data u should use Conv2d

Comment: But there is some relationship between these 19 channels and I want my model to be able to learn from it as well for classification. How do I solve it with Conva3D?

Comment: if so u shoud add dimensionality to your input array... np.expand_dims(X_train, -1) (this is for channels last)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're clear with what the code's doing.

1. For plain images you should use a 2D CNN. 3D CNN's are used for CT scans and MRI images.
2. Your input shape has to be the shape of the image, which does not include the number of examples. Your INPUT_SHAPE should be (19, 263, 179)
3. Your kernel size should have a number of filters = dimension of the conv layer. For a Conv2D layer your kernel_size would be for example equal to (3, 3)
4. In model.fit() you have to pass X_train, then y_train, then the rest of the parameters. How else will the model which labels to learn from?
5. In model.fit() the validation_data argument is a list of (X_test, y_test)

Hope this clarifies everything

Comment: But my input images are NumPy arrays with 19 channels here. There are some relationships between these individual channels and I want my model to learn from them as well for better classification. So I have to use 3D CNN right?

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but now I am getting this error -> "Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (740, 19, 163, 279)"